# Using credit after statement issued -- but paying in full?

Tags: credit-card, credit-score

If I get a statement with $10 on it, but charge 2 more after that it's no longer the same statement -- but if I still pay the $12 on it in the grace period I am still not charged interest.

My questioning is about the $2 and the following statement -- how will this work?

Since I paid in full before the due date (no interest), what will be of any money I charge after the statement is issued? Does it still get computed into the next statement somehow?

I'm not wondering how this will affect interest -- I'm wondering how this will help my score or not.

Answer (score 4):

For sake of clarity let me offer dates for 2 month's activity -

- Jan 1 - Jan 31 New card and you make $10 in charges
- Jan 31 - the cycle ends, a bill is cut for $10, due Feb 23
- Feb 1 - you charge $2 (or more)
- Feb 22 - you pay $10, your account is current, no interest has accrued.
- Feb 29 - The new bill is cut and it has charges made during February.

If, on the 22nd of Feb, you paid $12, the Feb 29 bill would show zero balance. This is of no value. Other questions here have discussed the fact that the credit agencies prefer regular usage, even 1% of the credit line. I suggest charging all gas, as it's regular, and not subject to the whims of overbuying. They are those who suggest that my grocery bill is 25% higher due to impulse buying on credit. I doubt you'll drive more just because you charged the gas.

Comment: Except hereabouts gas & groceries are significantly cheaper if you pay cash.

Comment: Do you live near Tiffle? Obviously, one has to use common sense. Where I live, it's a rare gas station that discounts cash, and no supermarket does. In your case, there might be other items that aren't discounted. If a store/gas station, etc discounted more than my reward rebate, I'd go to cash.

Comment: I don't know where s/he lives.  It's just a possibility to be aware of.

Answer (score 2):

Charges made after a statement's closing date simply go onto the next statement.

If, like most of us, you aren't being charged interest until that statement's *due* date, there is no advantage to prepaying the $2. You can just pay it when that statement comes in.

Prepaying it doesn't do any harm (except costing you a fraction of a penny of interest you might have earned by keeping that money in your own account), but you are making this harder and more stressful than it needs to be.

Comment: "Prepaying it doesn't do any harm" although it might result in zero utilization which is worse than 1%.

Comment: Yeah, but given how little this actually matters in real-world terms for most people most of the time...